# kill a range of jobs by jobspec

Tags: unix, kill, jobs

I can't find an answer to this other than get the jobspec and then `kill %jobspec`...

I have 46 jobs in the background of a tape backup robot which I submitted in a loop which are all stuck because of this error `Suspended (tty output)` which I've since found out means that I needed to enter my password before the process was sent to the background otherwise it won't start.

This is what I want to do `kill %[1-46]` but I have no idea if it will work as I expect. There seems to be no reference to killing a range of jobs like this anywhere (at least that I've looked in, like the internet...).

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thank,

Vince

Answer (score 2):

One option is to loop over the jobs.  E.g. In bash it looks like:

```
for i in {1..3}; do kill %$i; done
```

e.g.:

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do sleep 20 & done
[1] 26453
[2] 26454
[3] 26455
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 20 &
[2]-  Running                 sleep 20 &
[3]+  Running                 sleep 20 &
$ for i in {1..3}; do kill %$i; done
$ jobs
[1]   Terminated              sleep 20
[2]-  Terminated              sleep 20
[3]+  Terminated              sleep 20
$ jobs
$
```